Dynamic Render Meta Tags for ReactJs deployed on AWS Amplify
We have a deployed react frontend in AWS Amplify. Now we want to render dynamic meta tags, what will be the best design solution.
As of now we read the "index.html" file from the s3 bucket and created lambda function to return html content with replaced values.
If anyone suggest better architecture then it will be helpful. Thanks
